# Face detection algorithms

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, face-detection, face-recognition

I am trying to make an application for my graduation thesis which consists in the implementation of a face detection and recognition algorithm to detect the faces of individuals in a room with a video camera. So I'm looking for a "not so hard" algorithm that detects frontal and profile face, then a face recognition algorithm and use it with a face database.
So far I have found the Viola Jones algorithm and KLT algorithm. I don't want to use any API.
If anyone knows I would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: This question seems to be too broad for this site. What exactly are you looking for? Are you just looking for recommendations on which algorithm to use? Are you looking for someone to post a working version of that algorithm (I assume not since this is for your thesis). Also, why are Viola Jones and KLT not a good fit for what you are trying to do? You may need to ask a more specific question to get a meaningful response here, and you will definitely need to provide more details of what your needs and constraints are

Comment: @KevinWells I'm looking for recommendations since i'm new in this image/video processing thing and google isn't helping me so much in finding one (because i need to implement it) that is not hard for me because i'm just a student.

Comment: And what about the Viola Jones and KLT algorithms makes them insufficient for your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most used algorithm (already implemented in most of the libraries) is the Viola-Jones.

But you will find everything you need on these two specialized web-sites:

- https://facedetection.com
- http://www.face-rec.org